# Проверка RSA подписи

Tags: java, rsa

Добрый день. Занялся я подключение киберплата, все бы хорошо но не получается у меня проверить подпись строки которую они присылают.

Входные данные:

1. Строка на которую имеем подпись `String text = "action=check&number=00842&amount=10.54&type=1"`
2. Подпись

   ```
   String sign = "C41545C19E86D0001F11D9D98EA6630EFAE4AB26AEC5933E05B5ADE7B6571B7B0FF5230F33B306D174290D3E6FAF1133A6FD1F0155A5D04294DE7DD0A20E3B037884121D399CEF9D91EC519AB56B67448E116EAF8629293E1F66A780E0028A2EC7C831D1F5ADF68B9703B576B30D80DA940187A23104A9304A74A9C86AD6E68B";`
   ```
3. Публичный ключ http://yadi.sk/d/u892DkgA3zh9a

Так я загружаю публичный ключ

```
    PEMReader reader = new PEMReader(new FileReader(f));
        Object obj;
        PublicKey pubKey = null;
        while ((obj = reader.readObject()) != null) {
           if (obj instanceof PublicKey) {
                pubKey = (PublicKey) obj;
           }
        }
```

Если после этого сделать `Sytem.out.println(pubKey)`, на выходе получаю модуль и публичную экспоненту. 
Алгоритм ключа RSA, формат X.509.

Так я делаю проверку подписи:

```
try {
        byte [] data = text.getBytes();
        byte [] subscript = subscriptText.getBytes();
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("RSA","BC");
        signature.initVerify(pubKey);
        signature.update(data);
        System.out.println(signature.verify(subscript) ? "Подписано верно!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!": "Подписано не верно");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Но результат всегда один. Делал свою подпись на данную строку(своим приватным ключом) и пытался проверить подпись своим открытым ключом, но тоже получил отрицательный ответ. Ошибки ни какой не выводит, просто говорит не правильная подпись.

Помогите проверить подпись.

```
**Update**
техподдержка киберплата скинула код на perl в котором проверка проходит успешно. осталось только реализовать все на Java

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

my $cyberplat_message='action=check&number=00842&amount=10.54&type=1&sign=C41545C19E86D0001F11D9D98EA6630EFAE4AB26AEC5933E05B5ADE7B6571B7B0FF5230F33B306D174290D3E6FAF1133A6FD1F0155A5D04294DE7DD0A20E3B037884121D399CEF9D91EC519AB56B67448E116EAF8629293E1F66A780E0028A2EC7C831D1F5ADF68B9703B576B30D80DA940187A23104A9304A74A9C86AD6E68B';

my $message=$cyberplat_message;
my $signature_hex=$cyberplat_message;
undef $cyberplat_message;
$message=~s/\&sign.*?$//;
$signature_hex=~s/^.*?\&sign\=(.*?)$/$1/sg;
my $signature_bin=pack("H*",$signature_hex);
my $pub_key_string=`cat CyberPlat_RU_pub.pem`;
my $rsa_pub = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($pub_key_string);

if (!$rsa_pub->verify($message, $signature_bin)) {
print "Error";
} else {
print "Succes";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Меня во всей это истории смущает невинный `text.getBytes()` - при этом для перевода в байты, как известно, используется текущая системная кодировка. Аллаху только ведома какая она текущая кодировка у вас и у отправителя...

Здесь надо четко понимать какая должна быть кодировка исходной строки - я бы не стал полагаться и Аллаха и явно прописал ожидаемую кодировку

```
text.getBytes("UTF-8"); //например...
```

**Update**

Подпись надо перекодировать в байты из HEX'а примерно так:

```
public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hexString)
{
    static final String HEX="0123456789ABCDEF";        
    byte[] out=new byte[hexString.length() / 2];

    int n=hexString.length();

    for(int i=0; i < n; i+=2)
    {
        //make a bit representation in an int of the hex value
        int hn=HEX.indexOf(hexString.charAt(i));
        int ln=HEX.indexOf(hexString.charAt(i + 1));
        if(hn < 0 || ln < 0)
            return null;
        //now just shift the high order nibble and add them together
        out[i / 2]=(byte) ((hn << 4) | ln);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: ставил кодировки и UTF-8 и windows-1251 - это я делал еще в самом начале, сейчас просто отчаялся. 
Нашел краткое упоминание что подпись необходимо декодировать Base64.decod, но опять же результат отрицательным

Comment: @G1yyK Да это не фига не Base64 - а обычный HEX!

Comment: byte [] subscript = convertHexToString(subscriptText).getBytes();
public static String convertHexToString(String hex){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
            String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
            sb.append((char)decimal);
            temp.append(decimal);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

После конверта результат остался отрицательным

Comment: @G1yyK нет надо не так! Hex надо сразу в байты, а не через строку! См. апдейт ответа

Comment: Блин. Не работает. И даже не знаю куда копать. Нет никакого способа узнать где ошибка, где я накосячил?

Comment: @Barmaley, у меня закрались сомнения по поводу правильности открытия ключа. Вы не знаете может я что то не так делаю?

Answer (score 1):

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");
```

Должно помочь, у меня аналогичный код который вы изначально приводили работает, только получения объекта подписи делаю так.
И ещу

```
signature.verify(subscript)
```

измените на

```
signature.verify(Hex.decode(subscript))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, к сожалению, уже лет 5 не притрагивался к RSA. Могу посоветовать изучить на примере взаимодействия бота и сервера Lineage II. Там 3й и 4й пакеты взаимодействия "клиент-логин" используют RSA. В своё время очень долго искал информацию об этом протоколе, трудно это.